# Partially override a function in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
class Manager{
  function a(){
    $var1 = 10;
    $var2 = 20;
    var_dump($var1 * $var2);
    echo "<br> var1=" . $var1 . "<br>";
    echo "var2=" . $var2;
  }
}

class Sub extends Manager{
  function a(){
    $var1 = 20;
    parent::a();
  }
}
$s = new Sub();
$s->a();
```

Here, I am trying to override the value of `$var1` from `Sub::a()` then calling its parent function `Manager::a()`, hoping php will set `$var1=20` & show result  as `400`(20 x 20). But it doesn't seem to work. `$var1` is still equal to `10`.

Wondering if there a way to to partially override a function in php where local variables of functions can be overridden? specifically in this code, how can I get out of `400`, instead of current `200` ?

**[Edit]**

the `Sub` is just an example, I will have multiple child classes like `Sub1`, `Sub2`, `Sub3` & so on. so the each sub-class will try to set different value for `$value1`, like this:

```
class Sub1 extends Manager{
      function a(){
        $var1 = 20;
        parent::a();
      }
    }

class Sub2 extends Manager{
      function a(){
        $var1 = 99;
        parent::a();
      }
    }
class Sub3 extends Manager{
      function a(){
        $var1 = 50;
        parent::a();
      }
    }
```

Comment: you should use class property instead of local variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can set a default function parameter, but you cannot override the local values of a function you call.

```
class Manager{
  function a($var1 = 10, $var2 = 20){ // default value of $var1: 10; of $var2: 20
    var_dump($var1 * $var2);
    echo "<br> var1=" . $var1 . "<br>";
    echo "var2=" . $var2;
  }
}

class Sub extends Manager{
  function a(){
    $var1 = 20;
    parent::a($var1); // you set $var1 parameter of function to 20; $var2 is set to the dafault value: 20
  }
}
$s = new Sub();
$s->a();
```

(btw. if you really want to *redefine* the function, you can use the runkit extension; but I wouldn't consider it.)

---

Also, when you have more subclasses, you can change them to match this format.

Comment: this won't work as I will have more than one subclass like `sub1`,`sub2` etc. Kindly see my edited question for that

Comment: @GaurishSharma change your subclasses to match this?

Comment: makes sense. Please edit your answer, so I can reverse my downvote :)

Answer (score 3):

Scope of the variables inside the class methods are always local. overwriting or calling parent method does not change anything.

I will prefer to use class property if i had to assign value dynamically and change it accordingly.

For example.

```
class Manager {

    protected $_var1;
    protected $_var2;

    function a() {
        $this->_var1 = 10;
        $this->_var2 = 20;
        var_dump($this->_var1 * $this->_var2);
        echo "<br> var1=" . $this->_var2 . "<br>";
        echo "var2=" . $this->_var2;
    }
}

class Sub extends Manager {
    function a() {
        $this->_var1 = 20;
        parent::a();
    }
}

$s = new Sub();
$s->a();
```

This will overwrite the values and work the way you expect it to.

Hope this helps.